# How install fontTools in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a program in python 3.6.2(32 bit) in Windows, and imported the following libraries.

```
from tkinter import font
from fontTools.ttLib import TTFont
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter.font as font
from tkinter.ttk import Separator, Style
from tkinter.filedialog import *
import tkinter as tkfont
```

When I run the code, I get this error:

```
No module named 'fontTools'
```

When I install the module via this command:

```
pip install fontTools
```

I get the following error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement fontTools (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for fontTools
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: [Download it from here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#fonttools), install the whl file with pip and use it  **for windows**. Hope this helps

Comment: Very briefly, the repositories you search with **pip** do not include a **fontTools** package that is compatible with your present Python installation.  First, try installing **fonttools** (note the lower-case).  If that fails, try searching for on-line sources for the package with something like "download fonttools" and look for your Python configuration.

Answer (score 4):

As the [documentation states](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools#installation):

> pip install fonttools

It's all lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following command as below:

```
pip install --user fonttools
```